# Drools rule returns value null (not firing?)

Tags: drools, rules, kie

Iam new with drools. I created the following object:

```
package com.myspace.applicant;

public class Applicant implements java.io.Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private java.lang.Integer age;
    private java.lang.Boolean approved;
    private java.lang.Double money;
    private java.lang.String name;

    public Applicant() {
    }

    public java.lang.Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setAge(java.lang.Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public java.lang.Boolean getApproved() {
        return this.approved;
    }

    public void setApproved(java.lang.Boolean approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }

    public java.lang.Double getMoney() {
        return this.money;
    }

    public void setMoney(java.lang.Double money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    public java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(java.lang.String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Applicant(java.lang.Integer age, java.lang.Boolean approved,
            java.lang.Double money, java.lang.String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.approved = approved;
        this.money = money;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

and a *.drl file which contains the rule:

```
package com.myspace.applicant;

import com.myspace.applicant.Applicant;

no-loop

rule "approve applicants"
when
    $a: Applicant(age > 30, money > 1000, approved == false)
then
    modify($a) {
        setApproved(true);
    }
end
```

In Postman I tried to call the rule with the following body:

```
{
    "lookup" : null,
    "commands" : [ {
        "insert" : {
            "objects" : {
                "Applicant": {
                    "age": 28,
                    "approved": false,
                    "money": 10000,
                    "name": "boehlen"
                }
            },
            "disconnected" : false,
            "out-identifier": "Applicant",
            "return-object" : true,
            "entry-point" : "DEFAULT"
        }
    }, {
        "fire-all-rules" : {}
    } ]
}
```

I got the following answer:

```
{
  "type" : "SUCCESS",
  "msg" : "Container Applicant_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT successfully called.",
  "result" : {
    "execution-results" : {
      "results" : [ {
        "value" : null,
        "key" : "Applicant"
      } ],
      "facts" : [ {
        "value" : null,
        "key" : "Applicant"
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, that my value is **null** instead of the object I expect as a response. The server.log is empty and I do not see what is wrong. Please could you help me.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule only triggers if the Applicant age is greater than 30. Your input value includes an age of 28.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I changed the value to 31. Still the same result, => null. So, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. It was a typo. Instead of "results" I had to write "result". Thanks a